# Telegram Bot sendDocument problem with filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I try to send .pdf file like this:

```
await bot.sendDocument(chatId, fs.readFileSync(outputFilePath), {}, {
    filename: outputFileName,
    contentType: 'application/pdf',
})
```

But if the filename includes at least one of these characters "§¤&`£€'", all such characters will be filtered out.

Moreover, these characters are valid for the name of the file itself.

Researching the problem, I came to the conclusion that I need to use 'percent-encoding', but how can I use this with 'sendDocument' method?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const caption = { caption: "caption" ?? path.basename(outputFilePath) };
const file = { filename: path.basename(outputFilePath), source: await fs.createStream(outputFilePath)};

await bot.telegram.sendDocument(chatId, file, caption);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this code example doesn't match the method typing and throws an error